# python3のmemory_profilerについて

Tags: python, python3

memory_profilerを使ってメモリを測っています。
以下のリンクを参考にして同じコードを書きましたが、メモリ消費表示の桁数が違います。
なぜでしょうか？
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.07-timing-and-profiling.html

```
 Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
 ================================================
     1     52.5 MiB     52.5 MiB   def sum_of_lists(N):
     2     52.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       total = 0
     3     52.5 MiB     -7.0 MiB       for i in range(5):
     4     80.5 MiB -49425205.4 MiB           L = [j ^ (j >> i) for j in range(N)]
     5     87.1 MiB     29.8 MiB           total += sum(L)
     6     52.4 MiB   -153.1 MiB           del L # remove reference to L
     7     50.7 MiB     -1.8 MiB       return total
```

追記：
実行環境
pipenv: version 2018.11.26
python: python3.6.5
OS    : macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
ブラウザ: Chrome 70.0.3538.110（Official Build） （64 ビット）

Comment: 何回実行しても同じ結果になりますでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 3回まで実行して数値は少し変わりますがほぼ同じ結果です。

Comment: 英語版 Stack Overflow にも似た質問が[ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47490896/5989200)と[ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51077423/5989200)にあるのですが現状未解決でした。環境によって再現する問題のようです。可能であれば、lynnさんの環境情報（バージョンやOS、ブラウザなど）を追記して頂けると、同じ環境を持っている人が試してくれるかもしれません。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます！追記します。

Comment: Google colab の ipython で memory_profiler 0.54.0 を使って同じことをしてみたところ、[問題が再現しました](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1leQtRze6YmZ3GTY_la_o2I34xOMSvJ8a)。

Comment: ご参考: GitHubに関連しそうな [Issue](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/issues/211) がいくつかあります。

Comment: memory_profiler のバグかもしれません。[Issue を投稿してみました。](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/issues/219)